# Crystal Reports 2011 - How to Partially Format Text Object or Change Text interpretation?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, rtf

I have a crystal report2011 with one text object in it.
I am successfully able to enter text in it at runtime.
However, I want to know how to format only part of the text at run time.
I want the text of the text object to look like this ( As it displays on receipt):

"Received with thanks from **Mr Aditya N Bokade** towards 
the donation for **Construction of building** with sum of **Rupees Twenty five thousand**"

I hope you have understood my requirement.

The part of the text of the text box should be highlighted at run time.
Even font size of the highlighted text should increase. So that It will look like a real receipt on the crystal report and in the final receipt.
It should be somewhat like markup that we add for HTML or even in this textbox of the site!

It seems that When I go to report>Right Click>Edit text object >Select some text>Right click on selected text > Text formatting, I can do the formatting of ONLY selected text.

But I want this to happen at runtime.

I also feel that somehow If I convert the text interpretation of the text object to Rich text format, then I may achieve this.
I tried Right click > Format object>Paragraph but there was no text interpretation option available as written in many other forums.

Kindly suggest me any alternative way of doing it.
Please help me,I am in urgent need.
Thank you.

Comment: In the example given, which text is entered at runtime and which text is obtained elsewhere (eg. from the database)?

Comment: From memory- i don't think you can set text interpretation (rich or html) on a text object, only on formulas, database fields etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have already cracked it. Two options:

- Create a text object and write in the static text then drag/drop any database fields, formulas etc. You can then select fields or parts of text from within the text object and right click, text formatting.
- Create a formula field which contains your compound expression e.g. `'Received with thanks from <b>' + {table.field} + '</b> towards blah...'` and then set text interpretation to HTML